# Tailwind rn installed but not styling views

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, tailwind-css, tailwind-variants

This is my second go around installing tailwind rn for a project and I simply can't get it to work.

I ran `npm install tailwind-rn` followed by `npx setup-tailwind-rn` and I'm running it in development mode after changing the `tailwind.config.js` to scan the only app file:
`content: ["./App.js"],`

The `App.js` file in the meantime looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {TailwindProvider} from 'tailwind-rn';
import utilities from './tailwind.json';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {
  const tw = useTailwind();
  return (
    <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
      <View>
        <Text style={tw('text-blue-600')}>Hello world</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </TailwindProvider>
  );
}
```

My `tailwind.css` and `tailwind.json` are both populated with defitions for `.text-blue-600` and I receive no errors when running, but none of the styles I apply work.  Very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `tailwind-react-native-classnames` from **jaredh159**. No setup or extra configurations needed after installation. It works out of the box.

This package gives the flexibility of mixing styles.

Install using `yarn add twrnc` or `npm install twrnc`.

Get more info from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/jaredh159/tailwind-react-native-classnames)